# Null Checks for a large hierarchical object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, null-check

We have a large hierarchical object (worst possible legacy design) in javascript. The problem I am facing is that there is a list of null checks I need to perform whenever I want to access an element deep within the object structure.

Say I have a bank object which contains a list of customers and I want to get the address of the first customer,

```
if(bank != null ||
bank.customerlist != null ||
bank.customerlist.customer[0] != null ||
bank.customerlist.customer[0].address != null )
{

transactionAddress = bank.customerlist.customer[0].address;
}
```

This is just a small example,I cannot believe so many null checks are required
just to access a single value.

It there a better way around this?

Comment: encapsulate it in `try { ... } catch (e) { ... }`

Comment: It seems this question was a duplicate. My answer here is almost the same as [@kennebec's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2631521/1529630) in the other thread; I didn't copy him, tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own accesser function:

```
function access(obj, path) {
    var arr = path.split('/');
    while(obj && arr.length)
        obj = obj[arr.shift()];
    return obj;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var bank = {
    customerlist: {customer: [{address: 'foo'}]}
}
access(bank, 'customerlist/customer/0/address'); // 'foo'
access(bank, 'bar/foo/foobar');                  // undefined (no error)
```

---

Also consider using...

```
function access(obj, path) {
    var arr = path.split('/');
    while(obj!=null && arr.length)
        obj = obj[arr.shift()];
    return obj;
}
```

...if you want to use `access` with non-objects, e.g. you want `access('', 'length')` to return `0`

---

Explaining,

```
function access(obj, path) {
    var arr = path.split('/');
    while (
        obj /* To avoid `null` and `undefined`. Also consider `obj != null` */
        && /* Logical AND */
        arr.length /* Check that `arr` still has elements */
    ) {
        obj = obj[arr.shift()]; /* `arr.shift()` extracts the first
                                   element is `arr` */
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good option, im kinda new to javascript, can you tell me what exactly is being done in this while condition : while(obj && void 0 !== (prop = arr.shift())) ?

Comment: @DntFrgtDSemiCln It checks that `obj` is truly (to avoid `null` and `undefined`), it extracts `arr`'s first element to `prop`, and checks that `prop` is not `undefined` (I use `void 0` because `undefined` could have been altered).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! @Oriol  , also do you think the try catch blocks would help too?

Comment: @DntFrgtDSemiCln I have simplified a bit my code (since I don't know if it's faster to attempt a `shift()` or to check `length`, I use the simplest one)

Comment: @DntFrgtDSemiCln Yes, the `try catch` works too, but I find it ugly :) Also note that if an error is thrown in a `try catch`, there is a small performance penalty. No idea if it's worse than the penalty of calling a function, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use try catch block:

```
try {
    var transactionAddress = bank.customerlist.customer[0].address;
} catch(e) {
    // handle the error here
}
```